# Insert dependency in parallel makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to add an extra dependency to a rule in a parallel makefile. I might have found a way, but I'm in doubt. (I haven't written the original makefile and I'm not an expert in make.)

The original makefile looks like this:

```
VER = busybox-1.16.2
URL = http://busybox.net/downloads/$(VER).tar.bz2

export KBUILD_OUTPUT = $(ROOTDIR)/user/busybox/build-$(VER)

all: build-$(VER)/.config depmod.pl
    $(MAKE) -C build-$(VER)

build-$(VER)/.config: $(ROOTDIR)/config/.config
    mkdir -p build-$(VER)
    sed -n \
        -e '/_CROSS_COMPILER_PREFIX=/s:=.*:="$(CROSS_COMPILE)":' \
        -e '/CONFIG_USER_BUSYBOX_/s:CONFIG_USER_BUSYBOX_:CONFIG_:p' \
        $< > $@.uclinux-dist.new
    set -e ; \
    if [ ! -e $@ ] || ! cmp -s $@.uclinux-dist.new $@.uclinux-dist.old ; then \
        cp $@.uclinux-dist.new $@.uclinux-dist.old ; \
        cp $@.uclinux-dist.old $@ ; \
        yes "" | $(MAKE) -C $(VER) oldconfig ; \
    fi

depmod.pl: $(VER)/examples/depmod.pl
    ln -sf $< $@
```

I want to add a 'download' rule to the make.

```
$(VER)/: $(VER).tar.bz2
    tar -jxvf $(VER).tar.bz2
    touch $@

$(VER).tar.bz2:
    wget $(URL)
    touch $@
```

This rule must be executed before anything else. The parallel build prevent constructs like

```
all: |$(VER)/ build-$(VER)/.config depmod.pl
```

(This works in single threaded builds.)
My solution so far is this:

```
VER = busybox-1.18.5
URL = http://busybox.net/downloads/$(VER).tar.bz2

export KBUILD_OUTPUT = $(ROOTDIR)/user/busybox/build-$(VER)

all: build-$(VER)/.config depmod.pl
    $(MAKE) -C build-$(VER)

$(VER)/: $(VER).tar.bz2
    tar -jxvf $(VER).tar.bz2
    touch $@

$(VER).tar.bz2:
    wget $(URL)
    touch $@

build-$(VER)/.config: $(ROOTDIR)/config/.config | $(VER)/
    mkdir -p build-$(VER)
    sed -n \
        -e '/_CROSS_COMPILER_PREFIX=/s:=.*:="$(CROSS_COMPILE)":' \
        -e '/CONFIG_USER_BUSYBOX_/s:CONFIG_USER_BUSYBOX_:CONFIG_:p' \
        $< > $@.uclinux-dist.new
    set -e ; \
    if [ ! -e $@ ] || ! cmp -s $@.uclinux-dist.new $@.uclinux-dist.old ; then \
        cp $@.uclinux-dist.new $@.uclinux-dist.old ; \
        cp $@.uclinux-dist.old $@ ; \
        yes "" | $(MAKE) -C $(VER) oldconfig ; \
    fi

depmod.pl: $(VER)/examples/depmod.pl
    ln -sf $< $@

$(VER)/examples/depmod.pl: | $(VER)/
```

Problem is, I don't really know what kind of magic the depmod.pl rule is. Is it executed correctly, now that I've added an explicit empty rule?

Comment: Maybe I should add: The build seems to work. But I don't really know what the depmod.pl rule does. So ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd hate to answer my own question, but I think I've found the answer.

The dependency of the depmod.pl rule is not real/relevant in the original script.

The code:

```
depmod.pl: $(VER)/examples/depmod.pl
    ln -sf $< $@
```

Ought to be written:

```
depmod.pl:
        ln -sf $(VER)/examples/depmod.pl $@
```

So my extra empty rule makes no difference. In the new script, the dependency almost makes sence though.